# Python encryptor issues

Tags: python, encryption

I have been working on an encryption software and I got to the code given. But now I’m stuck. I need a way to get the encrypted letter out from the function.

```
    num = input()
    word = input()
    num = int(num)

    def encrypt(letter, var):
        if letter == "a":
            var = "m"
        if letter == "b":
            var = "n"
        if letter == "c":
            var = "b"
        if letter == "d":
            var = "v"
        if letter == "e":
            var = "c"
        if letter == "f":
            var = "x"
        if letter == "g":
            var = "z"
        if letter == "h":
            var = "p"
        if letter == "i":
            var = "o"
        if letter == "j":
            var = "i"
        if letter == "k":
            var = "u"
        if letter == "l":
            var = "y"
        if letter == "m":
            var = "t"
        if letter == "n":
            var = "r"
        if letter == "o":
            var = "e"
        if letter == "p":
            var = "w"
        if letter == "q":
            var = "q"
        if letter == "r":
            var = "a"
        if letter == "s":
            var = "s"
        if letter == "t":
            var = "d"
        if letter == "u":
            var = "f"
         if letter == "v":
            var = "g"
        if letter == "w":
            var = "h"
        if letter == "x":
            var = "j"
         if letter == "y":
            var = "k"
        if letter == "z":
            var = "l"

     list = list(word)
     if num == 1:
     if num == 2:
        var1, var2 = word
     if num == 3:
     if num == 4:
     if num == 5:
     if num == 6:
     if num == 7:
     if num == 8:
     if num == 9:
     if num == 10:
     if num == 11:
     if num == 12:
     if num == 13:
     if num == 14:
     if num == 15:
```

Basically what happens is the first section (ends with the carriage return) just takes the word you want to encrypt and how long it is. Then the second section is the actual encryption which would recive the letter it is encrypting and the variable it would be. Such as the input would be encrypt(y, var1) and it would output the letter y would be encrypted then outputted as var1. Then the final section (which is unfinished) would be what takes the word turns it into a list then turns that list into a single letter then it outputs that to the encrypter.

Can someone give help on the final section and how to get an output from the mid section.

Note: this is an encryper not a decrypter. That’s part 2

Comment: Your question is not very clear and too broad, but for starters you can't modify function arguments like that (`var` in your example) because strings are immutable (even if they were mutable you wouldn't be able to mutate them using the assignment operator `=`). You should `return` the encrypted character from your function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few problems.

- You repeat the same code a lot, which isn't needed; what you're creating is what's called a substitution cipher and you're basically just replacing specific characters with another specific character.
- You want to replace the letters one at a time and are looking to put the text in a string in a list to do so; you don't have to though, Python allows you to loop over a string just as easily as over a list.
- You are trying to modify a variable you passed to a function (`var`), but that doesn't work for immutable types like a string; you can either return a value from the function, or pass it a mutable type (like a list) and modify that.
- You picked a cipher that's very easy to guess; a substitution cipher is very easy to crack to begin with, but picking a cipher that's literally in front of everyone with a keyboard may be a bit much :)

This would do the same:

```
def encrypt(letter):
    key = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    cipher = 'mnbvcxzpoiuytrewqasdfghjkl'
    return cipher[key.index(letter)]

word = input()
letters = list(word)
encrypted_letters = [encrypt(ch) for ch in word]
print('Encrypted:' + ''.join(encrypted_letters))
```

That still turns the word into a list, but since the number you were reading didn't really affect anything, I left it out.

It returns the encrypted letter and those are captured one at a time in what's known as a 'list comprehension': `[encrypt(ch) for ch in word]`, resulting in a list of encrypted characters.

This still naively goes through 'encryption' one letter at a time, but it just looks up the position of the letter in the key, and then returns the letter at the same position in the cipher - a lot shorter.

It could be a lot simpler still though:

```
CIPHER = {chr(i + 97): replacement for i, replacement in enumerate('mnbvcxzpoiuytrewqasdfghjkl')}


def encrypt(s):
    return ''.join(CIPHER[letter] if letter in CIPHER else letter for letter in s)

word = input()
print(f'Encrypted: {encrypt(word)}')
```

Here, the cipher is created as a dictionary, which is the ideal way to look up a value (that's what it's for). And it's created outside the function, so it only gets created once, since it doesn't change.

The cipher uses the fact that the characters of the alphabet (in lowercase) can be generated by a function `chr()` by giving it the ascii code for a character, 97 for `'a'`, 98 for `'b'`, etc. That way, you don't have to include the alphabet in the code again.

The function just loops over the letters in the word itself and returns the encrypted word - already joined back together.

And instead of just adding the strings together in the print line, that uses a so-called f-string to print the returned value inside the string, making it all a bit easier to read and avoiding some complications in many cases.

Comment: I ran both codes and the first one has 3 errors but I have had plenty of issues with Sololearn having errors that other codes don’t so it might work. The second works. Thanks for the lesson tho. And I was getting the amount of letters used so that I knew how many variables were needed to run it. For example if it is 3 letters it makes var1 var2 and var3 encrypts each of them then puts them back together and prints them.

Comment: Ah, apologies, there was a stray comma in that code - removing it fixed it.